# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. i am receiving mentioned error for ODEINT operand. can you help me with that

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
  import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from scipy.integrate import odeint

L = 2
n = 10
T0 = 0

T2s = 20
dx = L/n
alpha = 0.0001
tau1=1
tau2=0.005
taus1=0.5
taus2=0.2
u1=20
u2=25
T1f=np.ones(n)* 60
T2f=85


dT1dt=np.empty(n)
dT2dt=np.empty(n)
dTsdt=np.empty(n)

dt = 1
now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

print('current_time', current_time)
def to_integer(dt_time):
   return 3600*dt_time.hour+60*dt_time.minute
   # Or take the appropriate chars from a string date representation.


T1=np.empty([n])
T2=np.empty([n])
Ts=np.empty([n])

t=np.arange(0,20,10)
for i in range(1,n-1):
    def model(T1, t):
        dT1dt[i] = (Ts[i] - T1[i] /tau1) - u1* ((T1[i - 1] - 2 * T1[i] + T1[i + 1]) / dx)
        return dT1dt
    dT1dt = np.insert(dT1dt,i,i)
    print('i', i)
    T10 = np.ones(n+i)*100
    T1[i]= odeint(model, T10, t)
    print('T1', T1)

    def model1(T2, t):
         dT2dt[i] = (Ts[i] - T2[i] / tau2) - u2 * ((T2[i - 1] - 2 * T2[i] + T2[i + 1]) / dx)
         return dT2dt
    dT2dt = np.insert(dT2dt, i, i)
    print('i2', i)

    T20 =np.ones(i)* 120
    T2 = odeint(model1, T20, t)
    print('T2', T2)
    def mod(Ts, t):
        A=(1/ taus2) - (1/taus1)
        dTsdt[i]=T1[i] + T2[i]
        return dTsdt
    #dTsdt = np.insert(dTsdt, i, i)
    print('is', i)
    Ts0 =np.ones(n)
    Ts= odeint(mod, Ts0, t)
    print('Ts', Ts[i])
```

can  you help me to solve it.
i am getting the error " setting an array element with sequence.  even though i have tried to make the array in same length as the function is, but still i am getting this error. 
  i am going to make the following differential equation :

```
dT1/dt = (Ts-T1/a) - u(dT1/dx)
```

dT2/dt = (Ts-T2/b) - u(dT2/dx)
dTs/dt = (T1-Ts/c) - (T2-Ts/d)

Comment: Which line is raising the error? Can you post the params passed to the function at that line? We need to be able to reproduce the error to debug it.

Comment: dT1dt[i] = (Ts[i] - T1[i] /tau1) - u1* ((T1[i - 1] - 2 * T1[i] + T1[i + 1]) / dx)

Answer (score 0):

You assign the result of the first odeint call to T1[i] - I assume it should be assigned to T1 to be in accordance to the other odeint calls. This part runs on my machine (no idea if the values it produces are correct).

```
for i in range(1,n-1):
    def model(T1, t):
        dT1dt[i] = (Ts[i] - T1[i] /tau1) - u1* ((T1[i - 1] - 2 * T1[i] + T1[i + 1]) / dx)
        return dT1dt
    dT1dt = np.insert(dT1dt,i,i)
    print('i', i)
    T10 = np.ones(n+i)*100
    T1= odeint(model, T10, t)
    print('T1', T1)
```